# JS app with crawlable content (detect search bots server side)?

Tags: javascript, seo, server-side-scripting

I am building a Blog as a JS app. The JS app will consume an Api for content.

I am considering having a server side script that detects search bots and if found responds with plain crawlable HTML from the Api, otherwise loads the JS app which then does a XHR request to get the content from the Api and update the DOM.

Basically, if the request comes from a bot we consume the API on the server and respond with plain HTML,

or,

if the request come from a 'normal' user agent, the JS App consumes the API to get the content and serve it to the user.

Are there any caveats in using this approach?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: @Kaiido I prefer, if possible, to keep the url free of hash fragments (#!) since this is more consistent with blogs and has less of a risk to frighten visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Search engines penalise sites that deliver different content to them and regular users.

Build the site with [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead.

Comment: But the content would be the same, no? I mean the HTML generated server side for the search bots, or client side for the user would be the same.